# Ошибки в индексации адаптивного сайта

Tags: seo, google-search

Есть 2 версии сайта расположенные на одном домене, но физически это разные темплейты.
Например это сайт:
example.com

Есть некая категория на этом сайте, с пагинацией. Мобильный и десктопный имеют разное количество артиклей в этой категории.
Например
example.com/category/2/ десктоп (конечная страница, больше не имеем)
example.com/category/8/ мобильная (конечная)

Гугл пытается грузить example.com/category/8/ с десктопа и натыкается на 404. Как его научить понимать что к чему (прописаны alternate и canonical на страницу категории без пагинации)

Comment: Как пользователь я бы желал больно побить разработчиков такого сайта, у которого работоспособность ссылок зависит от устройства

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте применить суб-домен/папку для мобильной версии, например **m.example.com** или **example.com/mob/**. Также примените мета тэги для различных версий вашего веб-сайта - **[инфо Гугл о разных URL](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)**. Лучшее решение - это применение отзывчивого веб-дизайна для вашего веб-сайта. **[Отзывчивый веб-дизайн (RWD)](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design)** - это настройка, в которой сервер всегда отправляет один и тот же код HTML ко всем устройствам, а CSS используется для изменения рендеринга страницы на устройстве. Дополнительно смотрите статью Гугл **[Основы отзывчивого веб-дизайна](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/)**. Лучшим решением для отзывчивого веб-дизайна, является применение техники **[AMP Accelerated Mobile Pages](https://www.ampproject.org/)** + **[примеры AMP](https://ampbyexample.com/)**.